# Как мне в PHPStorm сделать, чтобы у JS документация при нажатии Ctrl+Space также высвечивалась, как и у PHP (скриншоты внутри)?

Tags: phpstorm

Когда пишу код на PHP, если не допишу вызов какой-либо функции и нажму Ctrl+Space, высветится документация, где будут показаны наименования функций, начинающихся с тех символов, которые я написал. И где можно переходить по ним (по наименованиям функций) с помощью стрелочек - и тогда справа высвечивается их подробная документация.
Как мне сделать, чтобы с JS было то же самое? У меня у JS наименования функций показываются, а вот их документация - нет. Как настроить?
Прикладываю скриншоты.
PHP:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
JS:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в принципе, что в PHP, что в JS, quick documentation обычн показывает информацию из комментариев в соответствующем библиотечном файле. Но, начиная с 2018.1, мы улучшили документацию для стандартного javascript api - теперь там показывается документация из mdn (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29277). Судя по всему, у вас старая версия, попробуйте обновиться

Comment: Просто обновить PHPStorm и все будет работать?

Comment: насчет всего не знаю, но документация для `getElementsByClassName()` точно будет выглядеть по-другому:)